# touchUpInside event on a UINavigationItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

In my app's main view, I have a button that segues to a subclassed `UINavigationController` holding a `UITableViewController` to change settings.

To get back to the app's main view, I have this in the `UINavigationController` subclass:

```
navigationBar.setItems([UINavigationItem(title: "Back"), 
                        UINavigationItem(title: "Settings")], 
                        animated: false)
```

When I tab the Back button, the app segues back to the same view - but the navigation bar now only have the Settings item.

When I click the Back button, I want to dismiss the `UINavigationController` subclass and come back to my main view.

So how do I get a `touchUpInside` event on the `UINavigationItem` or is there some other way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out there's a very easy way of doing this:

- adding a `UIBarButtonItem` in the storyboard
- subclass the `UITableViewController`
- control-drag from the `UIBarButtonItem` to the `UITableViewController` subclass to create an action
- dismiss the `UITableViewController` in the action